# Improving statement obtained by Pigeonhole principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

In [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010615/room-full-of-flies), this statement is proven:

> Room is cube-shaped, with side 3m. 136 flies fly in it. Prove that at
>   any moment  one can encompass 6 flies with a sphere of radius 90cm.

Can the statement be strengthened in the sense that 6 is replaced with a larger number?

---

My intuition says that this is really possible.

Comment: This time I'd try to use a tight packing of the $136$ spheres (i.e. the coplanar centers form a hexagonal mesh)  and prove that at least a certain number of spheres (I guess we can go up to the $12$ adjacent spheres, i.e. $13$ flies)...